# Who is and isn't mind-controlled by the Red Room?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, black-widow-2021

In *Black Widow*, we learn that the Red Room organization mind-controls at least some of its members, such as the Black Widows and

> Taskmaster.

However, at least one member of the organization, Red Guardian, was involved of his own free will.

Was anyone else being mind-controlled? I'm most curious about the helmeted soldiers. They appear to have a lot of commitment to the organization and its leader but I don't remember anyone stating directly that they were being mind-controlled.

Comment: Wasn't the mind-control only for the Widows? The mind-control on the *spoiler* person was to save that person's life..

Comment: @Shreedhar I've not seen the film yet but everything I've read so far supports your view that it was only for the Black Widows. You might want to make it an answer.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot I'm trying to find the exact quotes from the movie to support the answer. Once I get it, i will post my answer.

Comment: I'm not. I think.

Comment: @shreedar What do you mean? They were cured the same way as the Black Widows, meaning the same or a very similar procedure was used on them. And they did just fine without the control.

Comment: I'm definitely not. I do hear Dreykov's voice in my head saying "Paul, stop assassinating people, we're not doing that any more", but I just ignore it and carry on.

Answer (score 6):

The only people confirmed to be mind-controlled by the Red Room and Dreykov are the Black Widows and Taskmaster.

> **Yelena:** And those agents you chemically subjugated around the globe. That was me.
>
> <sub>*Black Widow*</sub>

There’s no indication that the other agents working for the Red Room are mind-controlled. I don’t believe we see any of them exposed to the antidote so we don’t have any indication either way though.

Answer (score 1):

Specifically with regard to the guards with the helmets, when

> Dreykov realizes he doesn't have his ring, and says they need to go back for it,

they don't even slow down in their evacuation. Granted, they wouldn't have been being *actively controlled* at that time, but anyone who'd been under mind control previously would probably have at least paused at that point.